Access C++ functions from client side of Nuxt app via WASM
I have a web app written in Nuxt3. However my app has to share some logic with some other piece of software. That other software exposes a bunch of functions written in C++. Instead of reimplementing all those functions in TS/JS and thus ending up with two implementations of the same thing, I'd rather have a single source of truth and make use of those C++ functions directly.
My idea was thus to compile these functions to WASM and then call those functions from TS/JS. I only would need those functions on the client side, e.g. from inside onMounted() but I'm having a hard time figuring out how this would work.
Has anybody done this before or has an idea how to do this? I think there are multiple pieces to the puzzle:

obviously simply being able to import the js file that exposes the wasm functions. Both generated by emcc
ideally getting a nicer interface automatically which provides a typed TS interface
have both of the above update automatically every time I touch the .cpp file while the dev server is running, the same way any .ts file updates so I don't loose the extremely convenient rapid prototyping I can currently do with two parallel implementations.

